# List of External Users using my site

Tags: list

I have a SharePoint SiteCollection in Office365 which are being used by external users also. I wish to shuffle their permissions. The number is huge so its tedious to go to each subsite and check-permissions.

Is there a way to get a list of all external users with their permissions and permission levels so that changes can be made accordingly?TIA

Answer (score 0):

There are compliance reports that will tell you which external users have access to the tenant - but I don't believe it breaks it down into SharePoint sites and permission levels.

This has always been a weak part of SharePoint.  You have to either create custom code to report / manage it, or use a third party tool.  There are plenty of tools out there - I've found the best bang for the buck to be with ShareGate, but you may also want to check SPDocKit if you don't need any of the content tools.  More expensive, but with more features than the above tow are products by MetaLogix and AvePoint